# Merging Cells When same data flows

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where I have to combine Cells when Same data flows in.
I wanted to combine Cells for "proj_name" and also "snd_ba_name". I have tried some code but nothing seems to work.
Can some one please help on this
XML for this report is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
   <body>
      <asset>
         <entity>
            <id>page3</id>
            <entity-record>
               <id>bad7ce40-66d2-11e7-9a1f-f5876ea6a532#-</id>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc2</id>
                  <value>GCO BISO Mumbai</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_euro</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>proj_name</id>
                  <value>ABC</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_inr</id>
                  <value>-47500.08</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>rec_cc</id>
                  <value>01471A00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>snd_ba_name</id>
                  <value>A</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>fsi_code</id>
                  <value>F1770259000</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc</id>
                  <value>9478110804</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_inr</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_eur</id>
                  <value>-670.62</value>
               </field>
            </entity-record>
            <entity-record>
               <id>bad7ce41-66d2-11e7-9a1f-f5876ea6a532#-</id>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc2</id>
                  <value>GCO BISO Mumbai</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_euro</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>proj_name</id>
                  <value>ABC</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_inr</id>
                  <value>-11028.25</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>rec_cc</id>
                  <value>01470C00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>snd_ba_name</id>
                  <value>A</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>fsi_code</id>
                  <value>F1770259000</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc</id>
                  <value>9478110804</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_inr</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_eur</id>
                  <value>-155.70</value>
               </field>
            </entity-record>
            <entity-record>
               <id>bad7ce42-66d2-11e7-9a1f-f5876ea6a532#-</id>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc2</id>
                  <value>TaxOps-Bangalore-NOC</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_euro</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>proj_name</id>
                  <value>ABC</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_inr</id>
                  <value>139417.72</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>rec_cc</id>
                  <value>01470H00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>snd_ba_name</id>
                  <value>Tax Operations</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>fsi_code</id>
                  <value>F1770259000</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc</id>
                  <value>9478754400</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_inr</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_eur</id>
                  <value>1968.35</value>
               </field>
            </entity-record>
            <entity-record>
               <id>bad7ce43-66d2-11e7-9a1f-f5876ea6a532#-</id>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc2</id>
                  <value>GCO BISO Mumbai</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_euro</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>proj_name</id>
                  <value>ABC</value>
                      </field>
               <field>
                  <id>rec_cc</id>
                  <value>01470F00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>snd_ba_name</id>
                  <value>B</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>fsi_code</id>
                  <value>F1770259000</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc</id>
                  <value>9478110804</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_inr</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_eur</id>
                  <value>-112.37</value>
               </field>
            </entity-record>
            <entity-record>
               <id>bad7ce44-66d2-11e7-9a1f-f5876ea6a532#-</id>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc2</id>
                  <value>TaxOps-Bangalore-NOC</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_euro</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>proj_name</id>
                  <value>DEF </value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_inr</id>
                  <value>6971.10</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>rec_cc</id>
                  <value>01490B00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>snd_ba_name</id>
                  <value>C</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>fsi_code</id>
                  <value>F1770259000</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc</id>
                  <value>9478754400</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_inr</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_eur</id>
                  <value>98.42</value>
               </field>
            </entity-record>
            <entity-record>
               <id>bad7ce45-66d2-11e7-9a1f-f5876ea6a532#-</id>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc2</id>
                  <value>TaxOps-Bangalore-NOC</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_euro</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>proj_name</id>
                  <value>TSO-TAXOPS-C_9478754400</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_inr</id>
                  <value>27883.69</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>rec_cc</id>
                  <value>01470E00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>snd_ba_name</id>
                  <value>Tax Operations</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>fsi_code</id>
                  <value>F1770259000</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sending_cc</id>
                  <value>9478754400</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>total_inr</id>
                  <value>0.00</value>
               </field>
               <field>
                  <id>sum_eur</id>
                  <value>393.67</value>
               </field>
            </entity-record>
         </entity>
      </asset>
   </body>
</message>
```

XSLT Code I have tried is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="snd_ba_name" match="body/asset/entity[id[text()='page3']]/entity-record" use="field[id[text()='snd_ba_name']]/value" />
    <xsl:key name="proj_name" match="body/asset/entity[id[text()='page3']]/entity-record" use="field[id[text()='proj_name']]/value" />

  <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>  
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>  
  <xsl:template match="message"> 
    <html> 
      <head> 
        <title>Invoice Report</title>  
        <style type="text/css">body { font-family:sans-serif; position: relative; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 900px; margin: 0% 0%; padding: 0%; } hr { border:1px solid; border-bottom:1px; width:100%; } .page_break{page-break-after: always;} input[type=text] { height:25px; text-indent: 0.5em; border:1px solid black; background-color:white; } input[type=checkbox] { /* Double-sized Checkboxes */ -ms-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* IE */ -moz-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* FF */ -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* Safari and Chrome */ -o-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* Opera */ } .sqr_block { border:1px solid black; background-color:white; height:28px; width:18px; margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px; } .tableArray1 { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; } #BorderHidden{ border-bottom-style:hidden; border-top-style:hidden; border-right-style:hidden; border-left-style:hidden; } .break{ page-break-before: always;}</style> 
      </head>  
      <body> 
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%"> 
          <xsl:for-each select="body/asset/entity[id[text()='page3']]/entity-record[count(.|key('snd_ba_name',field[id[text()='snd_ba_name']]/value)[1])=1]">
         <xsl:sort select="field[id[text()='snd_ba_name']]/value"/>
            <tr> 

              <td rowspan="" width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">
                  <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">

                     <xsl:value-of select="count(key('snd_ba_name',field[id[text()='snd_ba_name']]/value)[1]) + 1"/> 
                    </xsl:attribute>
                         <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='snd_ba_name']]/value"/> 

              </td>  
              <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left"> 

              <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='proj_name']]/value"/>
              </td>  
              <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left"> 

                <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='sending_cc']]/value"/> 
              </td>  
              <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left"> 

                 <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='sending_cc2']]/value"/> 
              </td>  
              <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left"> 

             <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='rec_cc']]/value"/>
              </td>  
              <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">              
                <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='fsi_code']]/value"/> 
              </td>  
              <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right"> 
               <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='sum_eur']]/value"/>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/field[id[text()='sum_eur']]/value),'0.00')"/> -->
              </td> 
              <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right"> 
              <xsl:value-of select="field[id[text()='sum_inr']]/value"/>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/field[id[text()='sum_inr']]/value),'0.00')"/> -->
              </td> 
            </tr> 

        </xsl:for-each>   
          <xsl:variable name="TotalInvoiceERU" select="body/asset/entity[id[text()='page3']]/entity-record/field[id[text()='sum_eur']]/value"/>  
          <xsl:variable name="TotalInvoiceERU1" select="sum($TotalInvoiceERU)"/> 
          <xsl:variable name="TotalInvoiceINR" select="body/asset/entity[id[text()='page3']]/entity-record/field[id[text()='sum_inr']]/value"/>  
          <xsl:variable name="TotalInvoiceINR1" select="sum($TotalInvoiceINR)"/>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
              <b>Total Result</b>
            </td>  
            <td height="20px" style="font-size:10px;" align="right"> 
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(($TotalInvoiceERU1),'0.00')"/> 
            </td>
            <td height="20px" style="font-size:10px;" align="right"> 
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(($TotalInvoiceINR1),'0.00')"/> 
            </td>
          </tr> 
        </table> 
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Output should look like :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Invoice Report</title><style type="text/css">body { font-family:sans-serif; position: relative; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 900px; margin: 0% 0%; padding: 0%; } hr { border:1px solid; border-bottom:1px; width:100%; } .page_break{page-break-after: always;} input[type=text] { height:25px; text-indent: 0.5em; border:1px solid black; background-color:white; } input[type=checkbox] { /* Double-sized Checkboxes */ -ms-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* IE */ -moz-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* FF */ -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* Safari and Chrome */ -o-transform: scaleX(1.3)scaleY(1.3); /* Opera */ } .sqr_block { border:1px solid black; background-color:white; height:28px; width:18px; margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px; } .tableArray1 { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; } #BorderHidden{ border-bottom-style:hidden; border-top-style:hidden; border-right-style:hidden; border-left-style:hidden; } .break{ page-break-before: always;}</style></head>
   <body>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">Project Name</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">Sending BA Name</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">Sending CC</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">Sending CC2</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">REC CC</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">FSI Code</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">Amount in EUR</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">Amount In INR</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">ABC</td>
            <td rowspan="2"width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">A</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">9478090108</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">ASU GTB-IN-PUNE-NOC</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">0001855844</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">F1770259000</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">4105.19</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">290768.89</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">9478090108</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">ASU GTB-IN-PUNE-NOC</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">0001855844</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">F1770259000</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">4105.19</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">290768.89</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">Tax Operations</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">9478090108</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">ASU GTB-IN-PUNE-NOC</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">0001855844</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">F1770259000</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">4105.19</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">290768.89</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">9478090108</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">ASU GTB-IN-PUNE-NOC</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">0001855844</td>
            <td width="10%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="left">F1770259000</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">4105.19</td>
            <td width="15%" style="font-size:10px;" valign="top" align="right">290768.89</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td colspan="6"><b>Total Result</b></td>
            <td height="20px" style="font-size:10px;" align="right"></td>
            <td height="20px" style="font-size:10px;" align="right"></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would look like your desired output?

Comment: Added my output format to Questions